# Referencing object member from nested function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm having problems with the following bit of code (I've omitted irrelevant lines):

```
var audios = function(url){
    this.loaded = false;
    req.onload = function () {
        this.loaded = true;
    }
}
```

The object member this.loaded is not being updated to true when the XHR loads. And it definitely gets to the onload function.  I think I'm not referencing it correctly, but I can't work out how.  Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: are you trying to access it before the callback executes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: I create an instance of 'audios' in the global scope and repeatedly check it's loaded state until it is true.

Comment: that's a bad way to do it, but do you at least wait a little before each check? If not, the callback won't get a chance to run.

Comment: I use a setInterval to periodically check every 500ms... This is part of a preloader that uses XHRs to load files.  I've not found any other way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the second `this` refers to `req`. Try this instead :

```
var audios = function(url){
    var me = this;
    this.loaded = false;
    req.onload = function () {
        me.loaded = true;
    }
}
```